# Hive Error: both left and right aliases encountered in join'late_fee_charged'

Tags: sql, hive

This is my query, I need to join two tables based on two conditions
however I am getting this error-Hive Error: both left and right aliases encountered in join'late_fee_charged'
Also, Late_fee_charged is present only in one table

```
select z.* 
from (
      select a.*,b.*,
      row_number() over (partition by a.account_number order by a.load_date) as rn 
      from base a
      left join master b 
        on a.account_number=b.acct_number 
        and b.load_date>a.late_fee_charged) z
where z.rn=1
```

Comment: If you have any columns with the same name in tables base and join then your SQL will/should generate an error. In general, using * rather than listing the columns is a bad idea

Comment: Even after listing the required columns,I am still getting the same error

Comment: Is `b` a table?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Made the edits

Comment: Please update your question with the latest version of your SQL (with the columns listed). Have you confirmed there are no duplicates column names?

Comment: I am using HIVE, and there is no duplicate columns.

Comment: You could try moving “b.load_date>a.late_fee_charged” to a WHERE clause rather than as part of the join. As you have a LEFT JOIN you probably need to adjust it where the “a” record is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive doesn't allow non-equi joins ( b.load_date>a.late_fee_charged) combined with outer joins.

In your case, I would try something like this:

```
select z.* 
from (
      select a.*,b.*,
      case when b.load_date>a.late_fee_charged then 1 else 0 end as tst_col,
      row_number() over (partition by a.account_number order by a.load_date) as rn 
      from base a
      left join master b 
        on a.account_number=b.acct_number ) z
where z.rn=1
and tst_col = 1
```

This may mess up your row_number though, you'll have to test it with your data.